# Oracle Apex - make tabs region "sticky"

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle Apex version 20.2.0.00.20. I have a page with a content tabs region, and some (but not all) tabs have nested content tab regions. I am wondering if there is a way to make just the links portion of the content tabs regions "sticky", so that when scrolling down the page those links stick to the top of the page (I can't use the Region Display Selector due to the nested tabs).

I have a static ID, contenttabmain_container, assigned to the outer tabs region. I tried using the javascript [method described here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=apexbyg:sticky_region), e.g.:

`$("#contenttabmain_container").stickyWidget({toggleWidth:true});`

However, this doesn't work because it makes the entire content region sticky, not just the `ul` element within the content tabs region that contains the links. As a result, if the content tabs region is taller than the screen height it doesn't allow scrolling past the portion that fits on screen.

So, I am wondering if there is another method of doing this, or if there's a way to use this same method but target just the `ul` tag that contains the links.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite picture what you're describing, but when I use the region display selector, I generally position it in the breadcrumbs bar position so that it 'sticks' to the top of the page during vertical scroll.

Comment: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/tabs-and-region-display-selector

Comment: For design reasons I am using the tabs container region instead of the region display selector (as the latter does not allow for nested menu items). So, I am unable to use the breadcrumb region here. An example of the nested tab container region is here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/tabs-and-region-display-selector --> Tabs region --> Example 2

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a CSS class to your Tabs container:

[image]

2. Add the following JS in the init block:

```js
$(".my-class").find("ul").first().stickyWidget({toggleWidth:true});
```

If the answer is not correct please create a demo app, because is pretty hard to understand what are you trying to do.